# Centos 7 настроить репозитории по умолчанию

Tags: linux, centos

Как в centos 7 настроить репозитории по умолчанию ?

чтобы использовались стандартные mirror.centos.org

содержимое файла /etc/yum.conf

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1

# Note: yum-RHN-plugin doesn't honor this.
metadata_expire=1h

# Default.
# installonly_limit = 3
```

строчки с репозиторием оттуда удалены, там был неработающий репозиторий mirror2.nashirnet.com

Answer (score 2):

Файлы с адресами репозиториев хранятся в файлах, которые лежат в `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. Ищи и меняй там.

Comment: я знаю что они там хранятся, там адреса указаны нормальные mirror.centos.org

Comment: команда yum update выдает. 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.0/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.

Comment: а если `sed -i 's/mirror.centos.org/mirror.yandex.ru/' /etc/yum.repos.d/*` ?